# Blob binding in httpTrigger not working in VS2017 Azure function template

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

I want to pass the filename of blob to the httptrigger, through get request as below.

```
http://localhost:7071/api/CSVDataMigrationHttpTrigger/testdata.csv
```

Code for the azure function

```
public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = "CSVDataMigrationHttpTrigger/{name}")]
        HttpRequest req, string name,
        [Blob("csvdata-upload/{name}", FileAccess.Read, Connection = "AzureWebJobsStorage")]
        Stream inputBlob, ILogger log)
    {}
```

**inputBlob parameter is not resolved and it returns null.**

But if i give filename as "testData.csv" as below in the Blob parameter, then inputBlob get resolved properly.

```
  public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = "CSVDataMigrationHttpTrigger/{name}")]
            HttpRequest req, string name,
            [Blob("csvdata-upload/testData.csv", FileAccess.Read, Connection = "AzureWebJobsStorage")]
            Stream inputBlob, ILogger log){}
```

Comment: I tried with the same code, I can able to get the value of `name` as `test.csv`. Did you try with the latest SDK?

Comment: I can get the value too, the inputBlob is null

Comment: Make sure the `inputblob` is already available in the blob container. I tried the same and I can get the stream in the `inputblob` . Please make sure you uploaded the `test.csv` inyour blob container. The Stream inputblob will be `null` only if you not have the corresponding blob in that container

Comment: It is there, that is why second code works

Comment: I will check the spelling of the filename tomorrow

Comment: Do you have any update on this? Did you check the spelling ?

Comment: It was case-sensitive @Jayendran. Thanks on digging for me and pointing to me the right direction

Comment: Happy to know that you find this simple fix. I've provided my answer. You can accept/upvote my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out finally, the filename was case sensitive, when passed to blob. Hope it helps anyone who has the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Check whether your `blob` is actually uploaded in the Storage Container. The stream will be `null` only if the blob is **Not Exist**/**Unable to find in the container**